# Missing refrences in extracted dacpac

Tags: sql, sql-server, dacpac

I tried to extract a `.dacpac` of the msdb system database via

`SqlPackage.exe /Action:Extract /ssn:my-server /sdn:msdb /su:user /sp:password /tf:"some/directory"`

This successfully created a `.dacpac` file, however if I import into VS2022 and try to build it, I get a build error:

`Error SQL71501: Service: [ExternalMailService] has an unresolved reference to Queue [dbo].[ExternalMailQueue].`

This is the corresponding `service.sql` file:

```
CREATE SERVICE [ExternalMailService]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    ON QUEUE [dbo].[ExternalMailQueue]
    ([//www.microsoft.com/databasemail/contracts/SendMail/v1.0]);
```

On the live database the referenced `ExternalMailQueue` exists inside

```
- Service Broker
  |_ Queues
     |_ System Queues
        |_dbo.ExternalMailQueue
```

But apparently it is missing inside the created `.dacpac`. I could create this Queue manually inside the project, but since it is actually a system queue, that doesn't sound like the right way to solve this problem. What is the proper way to tackle this missing reference?

Comment: Try removing dacpac reference and add it again with "Suppress errors..." checkbox checked. On the bottom of add dacpac ref dialog.

Comment: Have you made changes to the `msdb` database? Because if not, Microsoft provides dacapac files for both `master` and `msdb` pre-done for you, installed with SSDT.

Comment: Yes, there are changes in the msdb database